# unable to load a dicom image using cornerstone

Tags: dicom

I am trying to load a dicom image using cornerstone library. I get an error - uncaught exception: loadImage: no image loader for imageId.
I have my image file named as image-1.dcm. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- twitter bootstrap CSS stylesheet - not required by cornerstone -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<h1>
jsminimal/index.html
</h1>

This is an example of the minimal use of cornerstone driven by javascript

<br>
<br>

In this example, javascript is used to image enable a div.

<br>
<br>


<div id="dicomImage" style="width:512px;height:512px;">
</div>

</div>
</body>

<!-- cornerstone depends on jQuery so it must be loaded first-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include the cornerstone library -->
<script src="cornerstone-master/dist/cornerstone.js"></script>

<!-- include special code for these examples which provides images -->
<script src="cornerstone-master/example/exampleImageIdLoader.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var imageId = 'image-1';
        var element = document.getElementById('dicomImage');
        cornerstone.enable(element);
        cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function(image) {
            cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the cornerstoneWADOImageLoader to loader DICOM P10:

https://github.com/chafey/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader

Comment: it still gives me the same error after using cornerstoneWADOImageLoader. I have the same code and the filename for the image listed as image-1.dcm

Comment: Try the following example to load a file from your file system (click the "Choose File" button.  The best way to learn cornerstone is by studying the numerous examples.   http://rawgit.com/chafey/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/master/examples/wadouri/index.html

Comment: The example application works and I was able to view my image when I uploaded it. I am trying to using your library to build an interface which would load DICOM images on a web browser. I was referring to your cornerstone.js file. I was unable to do so even after using the WADOImageLoader.

Comment: Where are you trying to load DICOM P10 from - the local file system or from a HTTP server?

Comment: The browser cannot programmatically load files from the local file system due to security restrictions in browsers.  The user must manually select the file via the <input> tag or via drag and drop.  The example listed above shows how to do this using the <input> element

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I finally made the application. It works now. I wanted to ask you this - Can we load a folder full of dicom images and view them? Would that be possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible with HTML5.  Google Chrome does have a custom extension for this though, check out http://sapphion.com/2011/11/html5-folder-upload-with-webkitdirectory/

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003 how did o manage to automatically load those DICOM images to your system? I am using cornerstoneDemo and to load images from Orthanc to cornerstoneDemo I need first to fill the JSON files. I would like to develop an automatic system for it.